# Reference a dynamically created control's Text property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to refer to a dynamically created label's .Text property but can't find a way.
If I try referring to label1.Text it won't let me because it hasn't been created yet.

I'm trying:

```
Page.FindControl("label" & i.ToString).Text
```

This doesn't work either, although you can access the control's .ID property that way.
Any ideas?

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 For Web.

Answer (score 2):

[FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) returns a `System.Web.UI.Control` which does not have a .Text property. You need to cast it to a Label. Try this:

```
Dim label = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("label" & i.ToString()), Label)
label.Text = "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

If a control is nested inside other controls, you need to find it recursively. **In addition, you want to cast the control to Label control before using Text property.**

Here is a helper method. It searches a control recursively.

### Helper Method

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
   if (root.ID == id) 
     return root;

   return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
      .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
      .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}
```

### Usage

```
var myLabel =  FindControlRecursive(Page, "label" + i.ToString) as Label; 
if(myLabel != null)
{
    myLabel.Text = "abc";
}
```